# Value of 'count' cannot be computed in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Here I'm trying to create one `subnet` per availability zone and then associate the `route table` with each of them.

```
locals {
  aws_region = "${var.aws_regions[var.profile]}"
  base_name = "${var.product}-${local.aws_region}"
  aws_avzones = {
    pro = ["eu-west-1a", "eu-west-1b", "eu-west-1c"]
    dev = ["eu-west-2a", "eu-west-2b", "eu-west-2c"]
  }
}

# ---

# Create VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "default" {
  cidr_block = "${var.vpc_cidr_block}"

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.base_name}-vpc"
  }
}

# ---

# Create public subnets - each in a different AZ
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  count                   = "${length(local.aws_avzones[var.profile])}"
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"
  cidr_block              = "${cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr_block, 8, count.index)}"
  availability_zone       = "${element(local.aws_avzones[var.profile], count.index)}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = 1

  tags = {
    "Name" = "Public subnet - ${element(local.aws_avzones[var.profile], count.index)}"
  }
}

# ---

# Create Internet gateway for inbound-outbound connections
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "default" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"

  tags = {
    "Name" = "${local.base_name}-igw"
  }
}

# ---

# Create Internet gateway routes table
resource "aws_route_table" "pub" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.default.id}"

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.default.id}"
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${local.base_name}-rtb-igw"
  }
}

# ---

# Associate public subnets with the public route table
resource "aws_route_table_association" "pub" {
  count          = "${length(aws_subnet.public.*.id)}"
  subnet_id      = "${element(aws_subnet.public.*.id, count.index)}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.pub.id}"
}
```

Unfortunately `terraform plan` renders an error:

> - aws_route_table_association.pub: aws_route_table_association.pub: value of 'count' cannot be computed

Why it cannot be computed? Terraform did not complain about that when the infra. was all up and running, I discovered this error only after the destruction when attempting to to recreate the infra.

Currently my workaround is to comment out all the `aws_route_table_association` blocks, then `terraform apply`, uncomment and then finish the job. Obviously this is very far from ideal.

BTW, I also tried the explicit dependency declaration like so:

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "pub" {
  count          = "${length(aws_subnet.public.*.id)}"
  subnet_id      = "${element(aws_subnet.public.*.id, count.index)}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.pub.id}"

  depends_on = ["aws_subnet.public"]
}
```

But it didn't help.

```
$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.11.11
+ provider.aws v1.52.0
```

Comment: I have never worked with AWS routing tables so I cannot answer directly. Could it be that you have a dependency cycle or some dependency on a value first computed by AWS when the plan is being applied so not available in planning phase??? Have you tried `terraform graph` to visualize your dependencies? If that produces an error too, you could stepwise remove some resources and just add outputs of interesting values instead to better understand what is going on.

Comment: I doubt it's a cyclic dependency, it seems it's more likely a [bug](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/6616#issuecomment-443488240).

Comment: show us the codes of `locals` how you define `local.aws_avzones[var.profile]`, seems you didn't set properly

Comment: @BMW If `local.aws_avzones[var.profile]` was defined incorrectly then the infra. would not initialize when I comment out `aws_route_table_association` block. But if you must to know, `local.aws_avzones` is simply a `map`: `locals { aws_avzones = { key = [] } }`

Comment: Please update the detail codes in your question, which has the format. I still think my guess is the right direction for you issue. If you can't give any sample, `[]` is useless for me, then we can't help. Sometime the codes can't be run properly is just some tiny mistaken.

Comment: @BMW Please see the edited question.